# Using Google SpreadsheetApp setNumberFormat, setting format as percent and not multiplying by 100?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I'm building a Google Spreadsheet from Google Analytics data using the APIs, and I'm trying to format some numbers.
Based on the [Sheets API Format page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats), I should be able to use `.setNumberFormat("00.00\%");` to set the number to two decimal places and clear the `%` with the slash so that it won't run it's multiplier on the number. But it is not working as expected. According to that page, the `\` character "Treats the next character as a literal value and not any special meaning it might have."

RAW DATA: 33.0923537840302
GOAL: 33.09%
ACTUAL RESULT: 3309.23%

If I use `.setNumberFormat("00.00");` I get the result I want, but it lacks the `%` on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cell.setNumberFormat("00.00");
cell.setValue(cell.getValue() + "%")
```

First you'll set the format to "00.00" then concatenate the percent sign to the format result.

[image]

Hope this workaround helps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ends up here, to do this as a `range` (as opposed to by cell like @Mr.Rebot's answer), you need to collect all the values from the cell range, then loop through that data and set the updated value of the cells.

I was working off of this [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script), so that is where `outputToSpreadsheet` comes from.

```
function outputToSpreadsheet(results) {
    /*
        Collect all the values of the cells
    */
    var resultsLength = results.getRows().length,
        getPercentNewSessionsData = sheet.getRange(2, 11, resultsLength).getValues(),
        getBounceRateData = sheet.getRange(2, 13, resultsLength).getValues(),
        getPageViewsData = sheet.getRange(2, 14, resultsLength).getValues(),
        getAverageSessionDurationData = sheet.getRange(2, 15, resultsLength).getValues();
    /*
        Using the results count (resultsLength), run down the rows and manipulate all the cell values
    */
    for(var i = 0; i < resultsLength; i++){
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 11).setValue( (getPercentNewSessionsData[i] * 1).toFixed(2) + "%");
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 13).setValue( (getBounceRateData[i] * 1).toFixed(2) + "%");
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 14).setValue( (getPageViewsData[i] * 1).toFixed(2));
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 15).setValue( convertToDuration(getAverageSessionDurationData[i] * 1) );
    }
}
```